# Passing parameter to .fromsql

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-like

I can not get this problem figured out and I am getting frustrated. I want to do a basic search for a person in the database and the following is working fine

```
 IQueryable<VwSomeView> dbresult = db.vwSomeView.FromSql("select * from vwSomeView where firstname like '%" + searchfor + "%' or lastname like '%" + searchfor + "%'");
```

but it is bad because of possible SQL injections. So I tried this (because I used it before to call a stored procedure and it is working fine)

```
IQueryable<VwSomeView> dbresult = db.vwSomeView.FromSql("select * from vwSomeView where firstname like '%{0]%' or lastname like '%{0}%'",searchfor);
```

which isn't working. I tried it with *SqlParameter*

```
SqlParameter para = new SqlParameter("search", searchfor);
IQueryable<VwSomeView> dbresult = db.vwSomeView.FromSql("select * from vwSomeView where firstname like '%@search%' or lastname like '%@search%'",para);
```

that's not working either.

Could someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: As i can i see You have typized the table-class... why You didn't use Linq logic?

Comment: IQueryable<VwSomeView> dbresult = db.vwSomeView.FromSql("select * from vwSomeView where firstname like '%{search}%' or lastname like '%{search}%'",para); . . . try this, it might work . @Morty

Comment: @MarcoDalZovo because I haven_t used Linq a lot yet that does not came to my mind at all

Answer (score 3):

Use @search as a variable in SQL (and not within a string) and it should work.

```
SqlParameter para = new SqlParameter("search", "%" + searchfor + "%");
IQueryable<VwSomeView> dbresult = db.vwSomeView.FromSql("select * from vwSomeView where firstname like @search or lastname like @search",para);
```

Comment: Internet is spotty today so I did not get your answer after I postet mine. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Well of course I figured it out only 10min after posting the question.
This is working

```
DbParameter para = new SqlParameter("search", "%"+searchfor+"%");
IQueryable<VwSomeView> dbresult = db.vwSomeView.FromSql($"select * from vwSomeView where firstname like @search or lastname like @search",para);
```