# EFCore 7, passing parameters to stored procedure via FromSql()

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am calling a stored procedure from my .net application using EF Core 7 which provides the of FromSql to execute the stored procedure.  However I am struggling to pass named paramaters.  This is what I have attempted so far and even sample code which ispretty much the same:

```
using (accountingContext db = new())
{
    var TransactionClassId = new SqlParameter("TransactionClassId", 3);
    var list = db.MonthlyTotals
                .FromSql($"EXECUTE dbo.Reporting_Monthly_Totals @TransactionClassId;", TransactionClassId)
                .ToList();
}
```

The above produces the error that FromSql does not contain an overload which accept s 2 arguments.

Is there a correct way to parametrized data using FromSql above?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing parameter to .fromsql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52715823/passing-parameter-to-fromsql)

Comment: [Passing parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/sql-queries#passing-parameters)

Comment: Just use EF Core Power Tools to go the mapping and calls for you

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem in your code is located in creating the **parameter** for the procedure.

Instead of your code:

```
var TransactionClassId = new SqlParameter("TransactionClassId", 3);
```

Try this:

```
var TransactionClassId = new SqlParameter("@TransactionClassId", 3);
```

Add the **"@"** symbol in the `SqlParameter()` method;

Comment: The `@` is actually not needed, most people use it to be consistent though.

Comment: try something like this than: 
var someVar = 3;
.FromSql($"EXECUTE dbo.Reporting_Monthly_Totals {someVar}");